# Unwanted Space in Border Transition

Tags: css, border, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I made a border transition for a div in CSS that basically has the border become visible in a clock-work manner.

**[Here it is](http://codepen.io/edsonmendieta/pen/LbdJOx)**

*Hover over the gray rectangle to see it.*

The code below just here since site asks me for it, please **see link**.

```
<div class="outerBox"></div>
```

***However***, as you can see in the pen, there is space between the edges of the gray rectangle and the border, and the ends don't meet up correctly.

Any ideas as to **why** this could be happening?

**Update**

Actually, found the solution.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Seems perfect in Chrome...

Comment: @TheodoreK. I actually figured out the issue and updated the codepen. It had to do with using the box-sizing property.

Comment: Good, remember that you can answer your own questions too in stackoverflow.

Comment: @TheodoreK. Yup, just did, thanks for stopping by, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the issue had to do with the way the width of the **border was changing the div element's box-size**.

Basically, making the border 2px was adding 2px of width (on each side I believe) to the div element and was thus causing the space and un-met ends.

The **solution** was to add the declaration

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to the ::before and ::after pseudo elements (and just to be safe I added it to the div element) and then the **width of the div element was no longer affected by the border width.**

If you click on the link in my question, you'll see that the border now encloses the rectangle nicely.

**To see the previous state**, just comment out the box-sizing: border-box; declaration instances.

Answer (score 0):

One even easier solution with multiple backgrounds:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: silver;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 10em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 10em;
}
.box:hover {
  animation: border 1s linear forwards;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red, red), linear-gradient(to left, red, red), linear-gradient(to left, red, red), linear-gradient(to left, red, red);
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    background-size: 0% 4px, 4px 0%, 0% 4px, 4px 0%;
  }
  25% {
    background-size: 100% 4px, 4px 0%, 0% 4px, 4px 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 100% 4px, 4px 100%, 0% 4px, 4px 0%;
  }
  75% {
    background-size: 100% 4px, 4px 100%, 100% 4px, 4px 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100% 4px, 4px 100%, 100% 4px, 4px 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: After some experimenting, I actually combined this key-frame method with what I already had: 

http://codepen.io/edsonmendieta/pen/ENLwEw

It uses two key-frames but I prefer it to what I previously had because it seems more readable/logical to me and I do prefer using ::before and ::after.

Comment: Sure. Glad to see `keyframes` ;)